# How to use UUIDField in a way compatible with South?

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-extensions

Normally, I can resolve DB migrations that crop up, but this one is baffling me.

I have a new model that I've created, with a `UUIDField` (from `django-extensions`) as the primary key.

```
# BaseModelNamed is just a mixin which provides some basic fields
# e.g. name, description, slug, created, modified
class UUIDObject(BaseModelNamed):
    uuid = UUIDField(primary_key=True)
```

I also have another model which refers to this model:

```
class ParentModel(BaseModelNamed):
    default_uuidobject = models.OneToOneField(UUIDObject,
        related_name='parent_model', blank=True, null=True)
    uuidobject_collection = models.ManyToManyField(UUIDObject,
        related_name='parent_models', blank=True, null=True)
```

...And an auto-generated migration:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    # Adding model 'UUIDObject'
    db.create_table('app_uuidobject', (
        ('created', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)),
        ('last_modified', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)),
        ('name', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)),
        ('description', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.TextField')(null=True, blank=True)),
        ('slug', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.SlugField')(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)),
        ('uuid', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=36, primary_key=True)),
    ))
    db.send_create_signal('app', ['UUIDObject'])

    # Adding field 'ParentModel.default_uuidobject'
    db.add_column('app_parentmodel', 'default_uuidobject',
                  self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.OneToOneField')(blank=True, related_name='parent_model', unique=True, null=True, to=orm['app.UUIDObject']),
                  keep_default=False)
```

However, when I try to actually perform the migration, I keep getting a migration error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1005, "Can't create table 'db.#sql-819_2ed' (errno: 150)")
```

From what I've deciphered, running `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` can provide more insight into the problem, and indeed, it reveals this:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
130424 20:34:02 Error in foreign key constraint of table ebdb/#sql-819_2ed:
 FOREIGN KEY (`default_uuidobject_id`) REFERENCES `app_uuidobject` (`uuid`):
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
```

**How do I use UUIDField in a way that is compatible with South?**

Alternatively, how can I resolve this migration conflict?

Currently, I am using the following packages:

- `django-extensions==0.9`
- `South==0.7.6`
- `Django==1.4.1`

**EDIT:**
I have tried adding `db_index` and creating an index in the migration, neither of which have been successful:

```
# ...
    ('uuid', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=36, primary_key=True, db_index=True)),
))
db.create_index('app_uuidobject', ['uuid'], unique=True)
```